# Counting the times a character appears in a text with RStudio

Tags: r

I have a character vector with over 300000 words/elements. How can I know, with the operator == how many times a specific word appears in that text?

```
question <- scan(file = "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt", what = character(), quiet = TRUE)
```

for example, for the word "digit"

Comment: Look at `str_count()` function in the `stringr` library.

Comment: `sum(grepl("digit", question))` yields `0`, but `sum(grepl("digit", question, ignore.case=TRUE))` gives `10`, those allow for substrings. The equivalent expressions for the entire string (no substring) is one of: `sum(question == "digit")` (for case-sens), `sum(tolower(question) == "digit")` (case-insens), or `grepl("^digit$", question)` (case-sens and analogous for case-insens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the length of all the entries that are equal to the `word` var.

```
word<-"digit"
length(question[question == word])
```

Comment: Seems useful but it gives "0" as result, and it can't be as the text has the word 10 times...

Comment: Because R is case-sensitive, it is not the same "digit" and "DIGIT".Try writing the word in upper-case ("DIGIT") and it should work.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. By the way, I discovered that it's not necessary to define "word <- digit", so I could get the answer just by putting the  word between quotation marks.                length(question[question == "digit"])

Comment: And, if I would like to do the same with a word that has an accent mark, how could I solve it? As Rstudio doesn't read the words with accent marks..

Comment: You can read words with accent marks with the proper encoding. You can set the `encoding` argument when importing a file into RStudio.